# How to use Wiki Media API tools inside a Wiki extension (WPMW) to write/add content to a page

Tags: php, wordpress, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

**Hey there!**

**Here is the scene:**

I am working on a **Wordpress** site that should have its users integrated to a **Media Wiki** setup. Everything is working great by using a Media Wiki extension called [WPMW](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WPMW). When users from Wordpress log in they are automatically added to Media Wiki user database and they become affiliated to the Wiki as well. **Success so far.**

**Here is what I need to do:**

I need to, upon Wordpress + Media Wiki user login (through the WPMW extension), find a way to update a single specific Media Wiki page based on information I gather from the current user on the process. For example: when the Wordpress user called **Olaf** (**Editor** role), connects to Media Wiki, I want to simply write (append) to a special Wiki page (called **Editor**) the name **Olaf**, that will be together with other existent names.

So I researched about **Media Wiki API**, and after following some examples, I was able to create a PHP file where, after being accessed on the server, it locates a specific code and append text to it (even using a Media Wiki template built previously). **Success again**, but only for stand alone use... I need to go to example.com/my-script.php to make it work.

**Here is the problem:**

I tried to to insert my API code inside the WPMW Extension, but it is obvious that things are not simple as that, and everything stopped to work. So, I wonder, what could be the correct way to, **inside a Media Wiki extension, call the Media Wiki API** and give instructions to it to append text to a Media Wiki page, based on **PHP variables** present at the moment of the WPMW login execution?

For example: When Olaf (Editor) is logged on Wordpress and goes to the Wiki, the WPMW Extension gets active and makes the bridge — by registering automatically the Olaf to the Wiki database (if it is his first time) — or by simply logging Olaf into Media Wiki site.

At this point, I am able to get from Wordpress, as variables, all data relevant to me, the **Username** and the **User Role**. But how to use them to **append** the **Olaf** name to a **Wiki page** called **Editors**?

**Here is my API code, based on examples I found:**

```
<?php
$settings['wikiroot'] = "http://example.com/wiki";
$settings['user'] =  "shangchi";
$settings['pass'] =  "my-password";
$settings['domain'] = 'Windows';
$settings['cookiefile'] = "cookies.tmp";

// Test: use a Wiki template to append to page
$prepend = "{{test}}\n\n";


function httpRequest($url, $post="") {
        global $settings;

        $ch = curl_init();
        //Change the user agent below suitably
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, ($url));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8" );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $settings['cookiefile']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $settings['cookiefile']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        if (!empty($post)) curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
        #UNCOMMENT TO DEBUG TO output.tmp
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); // Display communication with server
        $fp = fopen("output.tmp", "w");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp); // Display communication with server

        $xml = curl_exec($ch);

        if (!$xml) {
                throw new Exception("Error getting data from server ($url): " . curl_error($ch));
        }

        //var_dump($xml);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $xml;
}


function login ($user, $pass, $token='') {
        global $settings;

        $url = $settings['wikiroot'] . "/api.php?action=login&format=xml";

        $params = "action=login&lgname=$user&lgpassword=$pass";
        if (!empty($settings['domain'])) {
            $params .= "&lgdomain=" . $settings['domain'];
        }
        if (!empty($token)) {
                $params .= "&lgtoken=$token";
        }

        $data = httpRequest($url, $params);

        if (empty($data)) {
                throw new Exception("No data received from server. Check that API is enabled.");
        }

        $xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

        if (!empty($token)) {
                //Check for successful login
                $expr = "/api/login[@result='Success']";
                $result = $xml->xpath($expr);

                if(!count($result)) {
                        throw new Exception("Login failed");
                }
        } else {
                $expr = "/api/login[@token]";
                $result = $xml->xpath($expr);

                if(!count($result)) {
                        throw new Exception("Login token not found in XML");
                }
        }

        return $result[0]->attributes()->token;
}


try {
        global $settings;
        $token = login($settings['user'], $settings['pass']);
        login($settings['user'], $settings['pass'], $token);

        // get edit token
        $result = httpRequest($settings['wikiroot'] . "/api.php?action=query&format=json&meta=tokens");

        $result = json_decode($result);
        $editToken = $result->query->tokens->csrftoken;

        // Get a specific wiki page: Main Page for testing
        $result = httpRequest($settings['wikiroot'] . "/api.php?action=query&titles=Main%20Page&format=json&aplimit=500");
        $result = json_decode($result);
        $allpages = $result->query->pages;

        foreach ($allpages as $page) {
            echo "Fetching '{$page->title}' ({$page->pageid})...\n";
            $revisions = httpRequest(sprintf($settings['wikiroot'] . "/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvlimit=1&format=json&rvprop=content&titles=%s", urlencode($page->title)));
            $revisions = json_decode($revisions);
            if (isset($revisions->error)) {
                echo "ERROR: " . $revisions->error->info . "\n";
                continue;
            }
            $content = $revisions->query->pages->{$page->pageid}->revisions[0]->$star;
            if (preg_match("/\{\{migration_/", $content)) {
                echo "Already marked ... skipping.\n";
                continue;
            }
            echo "Updating...";
            // add text to content and edit page
            $content = $prepend . $content;
            $post = sprintf("title=%s&text=%s&token=%s", urlencode($page->title), urlencode($content), urlencode($editToken));
            $result = httpRequest($settings['wikiroot'] . "/api.php?action=edit&format=json", $post);
            echo "done\n";
        }
        echo ("Finished (".sizeof($allpages)." pages).\n");
} catch (Exception $e) {
        die("FAILED: " . $e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, see [this article](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Calling_internally) for the correct way to call the API internally.

Second, the right way to react to an event is by using a [hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks) (in your case, probably [AddNewAccount](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/AddNewAccount)).

Third, are you sure you want to do this by editing a normal page? Creating a special page that just generates the list of users on the fly seems much less hassle to me.

Comment: Thank you, Tgr. Thanks for your directions. The project is paused now, my colleagues are looking for a different approach. Regards!